# Creating threads for interrogate some equipmet

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

i am trying to get data from equipment and created class that will make a socket by given via attributes IP. As thread starting alone everything goes well, but when i start second thread with another IP both of threads getting same argument.

```
public static String addressFiorenza = "192.168.9.201";  //Fiorenza
public static String addressFriulmac = "192.168.10.191";  //Friulmac
public static int port = 9761;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Thread friulmac = new threadForMachine(addressFriulmac, port);
    friulmac.start();

    Thread fiorenza = new threadForMachine(addressFiorenza, port);
    fiorenza.start();}
```

Silly question, i suggest, but why is it so?

upd: Sorry, here is threadForMachine class:

```
public class threadForMachine extends Thread implements Runnable {

    private static Socket s;
    public static String address;
    public static int port;

    byte[] requestBothRegTime = {(byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x16, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x26, (byte) 0x8E};
    byte[] requestForStatus = {(byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x1A, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0x8C};
    byte[] requestForOnTimes = {(byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x18, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x47, (byte) 0x4D};

    String inProgress = "3425680";
    String inIdle = "1328200";
    boolean isStarted;

    public threadForMachine(String IPAddress, int port) {
        this.address = IPAddress;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run() {

        System.out.print("Current status of" + address + " is: ");
        try {
            if (status() == true) {
                System.out.println("ONLINE");
            } else {
                System.out.println("OFFLINE");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(threadForMachine.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        do {
            try {
                getRequest(address, "Fiorenza");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(threadForMachine.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } while (true);

    }

    private void getRequest(String IP, String machineID) throws IOException {

        if (status() == true && isStarted == false) {
            isStarted = true;
            System.out.println("Time is " + getUptime());
            System.out.println("Times on " + getOnTimes());
            System.out.println("ITS ALIVE!!!");
        }
        if (status() == false && isStarted == true) {
            isStarted = false;
            System.out.println("ITS DEAD!!!!");
        }
    }

    public boolean status() throws IOException {
        String status = workFlow(requestForStatus, address, port, 7);
        if (status.equals(inProgress)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int getUptime() throws IOException {
        int upTime = Integer.parseInt(workFlow(requestBothRegTime, address, port, 7));
        return upTime;
    }

    public int getOnTimes() throws IOException {
        int onTimes = Integer.parseInt(workFlow(requestForOnTimes, address, port, 7));
        return onTimes;
    }

    public static String workFlow(byte[] comm, String address, int port, int length) throws IOException {
        String dataBlock = "";

        try {
            byte inp[] = new byte[10];
            s = createSocket(address, port);
            s.getOutputStream().write(comm);
            s.setSoTimeout(1000);
            Thread.sleep(250);
            s.getInputStream().read(inp);
            dataBlock = Integer.toString(fromHex(getTime(inp, length)));
            getTime(inp, length);
            s.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("init error: " + e.getMessage());
            if (e.getMessage().contains("Read timed out")) {
                System.out.println("Connection lost. Attempting to reconnect");
                s.close();
            }
        }
        return dataBlock;
    }

    public static Socket createSocket(String address, int port) throws Exception {
        Socket socket = new Socket(address, port);
        return socket;
    }

}
```

Comment: show the code for `threadForMachine`

Comment: and by the way: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: We can only guess what the code does and what the problem is. We cannot help you.

Comment: Could you elaborate what is bothering you with both threads getting same argument? Could the threads operating properly or showing any unexpected behavior?

Comment: OK. I will rename my classnames as it recommended. I hope it wil resolve my problem ) 
BTW, according to stuation, i need to understand how to create two or more threads with different argu.... damn... that was realy silly question... Thank you, guys.

Comment: They are getting the same argument because this is the way you designed your `ThreadForMachine` class. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58609382/2055998

Answer (score 3):

```
private static Socket s;
public static String address;
public static int port;
```

These three fields can not be static. Remove the `static` keyword.

The method `public static String workFlow()` also needs to be non-static.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/413904/1616627) to the question [What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)